# unable to set initial pose in gazebo spawn_urdf_model (groovy)

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

(cross-posting from [answers.ros.org](http://answers.ros.org/question/51295/unable-to-set-initial-pose-in-gazebo-spawn_urdf_model-groovy/))

In the update from Fuerte to Groovy, I  seem to have lost the ability to spawn an object at a given pose. Steps that reproduce this reproduce this problem (after updating to groovy):

```
roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch
rosrun xacro xacro.py `rospack find gazebo_worlds`/objects/table.urdf.xacro > /tmp/table.urdf
rosrun gazebo spawn_model -urdf -file /tmp/table.urdf -x 2 -y 2 -z 2 -model table_model
```

The table will spawn at (0,0,0). Can someone confirm if this is a bug?

Thanks!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1097/unable-to-set-initial-pose-in-gazebo-spawn_urdf_model-(groovy)/) by [piyushk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/131/piyushk/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 138 on 2013-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This issue has been ticketed [#5607](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5607).

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/131/piyushk/) with karma: 138 on 2013-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0